# ASP.NET Applicationuser ICollection Entity insert UserId null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ApplicationUser class and with a ICollection like below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Info> Infos { get; set; }           

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {            
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }        
}
```

And Info Class:

```
public partial class Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

And when I create a applicationuser like this:

```
IList<Info> infos = new List<Info>() { new Info() { Address = "testAddr"} };
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Addresses = a };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

This will occur validation error:UserId is required.Is any thing I missed?

Comment: I assume you do dbcontext.SaveChanges() below where you create a applicationuser?

Comment: No,I just use the Visual studio build-in example so the following is something like:if (result.Succeeded)....

Comment: Ok I see, so your list of `infos` only assigned `Address = "testAddr"` and your UserId in model is `[Required]`. I think you need to assign UserId into your list as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Infos` class, the `UserId` property doesn't relate to the navigation property `AspNetUser` at all, this is why it is failing. You either need to name them correctly:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(128)]
public string UserId { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Or you can add a `ForeignKey` attribute:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(128)]
public string UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,I tried the both and still not working.after googled some articles I tried remove UserId property in Info class and in modelBuilder add like:
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Info)
                .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("UserId"));

It works!but I need the UserId property in info class.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your code , you need to store multiple address associated to a user. Your UserId property is decorated with `[Required]` attribute therefore you will need to store `UserId` along with `Address`, the main problem is that `UserId` will be auto generated after you do `UserManager.CreateAsync` . So what I suggest is that you assign the list of address after user has been successfully created.

```
`var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,Addresses =a };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if(result.Succeeded)
{
     //assign list of address to user
     IList<Info> infos = new List<Info>() { new Info() { Address ="testAddr",UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()} }
     dbcontext.SaveChanges()
     //login here
}`
```

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: I tried remove require attribute then create user  in the same way like the origin code then it wokrs.I guess this is what I want!

Comment: Yeah the` [Required]` attribute is preventing you from creating user because you must assign it beforehand. Actually you can remove the UserId property since you have AspNetUser property and you can call it like AspNetUser.UserId which is the same thing.See which is the better workaround for you. Cheers~  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want UserId to be auto-incremented? Because right now it is not set anywhere. You receive this error because you defined that this field is required:

```
 [Required]
 [StringLength(128)]
 public string UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried remove require attribute then it works!thanks